# PHP $xpath->query expression not working

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

PHP xpath query not working. any idea?

**Problem # 1**
HTML Source:

```
<tr>
    <td class="abc pqr xyz">Some contents i want to capture</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="abc pqr xyz">more content i want to capture too</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="abc pqr xyz">all row in this table i want to capture</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="abc pqr xyz">they are all pokemon, i want to capture</td>
</tr>
```

PHP i tried:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/";

$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$text = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($text);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$divs = $xpath->query('//div/@class="abc pqr xyz"/');
foreach($divs as $b){
    //echo $b->name.'<br />';
    print_r($b);
}
```

**But nothing came, any help for the right expression for this query?**

---

**Problem # 2**
i wanted to check if i am getting content, so i tried this and got all href links:

```
$divs = $xpath->query('//a/@href');
foreach($divs as $b){
    print_r($b); // this is line #19
}
```

I got this error:

```
DOMAttr Object
Warning: print_r(): Not yet implemented in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\index.php on line 19
```

any idea, why i am getting this warning?

---

**Problem # 3**

```
                    <td colspan="2" style="">
                        <h3><a href="http://www.example.com/?id=xx" title="View more">I am not sure about the title</a>

                                <small class="comeoneman andwomen">Not a shoe</span>

                        </h3>

                        <div class="blahblah">This is just blah blah blah</div>                     

                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="">
                        <h3><a href="http://www.example.com/?id=xx" title="View more">I am not sure about the title</a>

                                <small class="comeoneman andwomen">No a shoe</span>

                        </h3>

                        <div class="blahblah">This is just blah blah blah</div>                     

                    </td>
```

any idea how can i get this info and convert it to array like this:

```
array (
  title => I am not sure about the title,
  link => http://www.example.com/?id=xx,
  small => not a shoe,
  blahblah => This is just blah blah blah
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem #1

Based on your markup, you're trying to target `<td>` tags, but in your query, it's `//div`, which doesn't make sense. Target `<td>`'s:

```
$rows = $xpath->query('//tr/td[@class = "abc pqr xyz"]');
foreach($rows as $b){
    echo $b->nodeValue . '<br/>';
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jdTh3x)

#### Problem #2

This is most likely related to this issue:

> https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61858&edit=1

#### Problem #3

You could just continue to use xpath to target the desired values. Select all those `<td>`'s and from there, just use each of them as the context node:

```
$data = array();
$td = $xpath->query('//td');
foreach($td as $b){
    $data[] = array(
        'title' => $xpath->evaluate('string(./h3/a)', $b),
        'link' => $xpath->evaluate('string(./h3/a/@href)', $b),
        'small' => trim($xpath->evaluate('string(./h3/small)', $b)),
        'blahblah' => trim($xpath->evaluate('string(./div[@class="blahblah"])', $b)),
    );
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DeiPVZ)

Comment: many many thanks. although i was digging this site and found alternative using getElementsByTagName: $table = $xpath->query('//table[@id="tableIDwillBeHere"]')->item(0); 
$rows = $table->getElementsByTagName("tr"); thanks again.

Comment: @crazymoin yes you could do that too also, glad this helped

Comment: Excelent.Thank you very much. I was looking for some function that would return node text directly like that `string()` function.