# Unexpected PHP error: Not yet implemented

Tags: php

I've recently upgraded my environment to PHP 5.6 and now my code is generating a warning when it runs:

```
Warning: CPage::findOnPageLinks(): Not yet implemented in / .. /crawler/page.class.php on line 162
```

Stepping through the code and it successfully enters the function and then throws that error when I try to step through an - seemingly - unrelated array.

I'm baffled as to where this is coming from and what it means.

It's being thrown when I try to step through a list of XML nodes:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $this->xml );
set_error_handler( array( $this, 'XMLerrorHandler' ) );
$nodeList = $xpath->query( $xPathQuery );
restore_error_handler();

foreach( $nodeList as $node ) # <<<<---
```

Comment: It'd be great if you included that code too...so we can actually help.

Comment: Yep, sorry... think that's the cause of it. Will do that now.

Comment: Something to do with extracting the node from the nodeList.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP $xpath->query expression not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080875/php-xpath-query-expression-not-working)

Bug in PHP it seems.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61858&edit=1